# Android create simple socket

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

> PROBLEM AFTER DISABLE FIREWALL IN LINUX SOLVED

i'm wrote simple application on Android and NodeJs and i'm trying to create connection between Android and Nodejs.

**PROBLEM is unable to connect localhost but i can connect to `http://socket.io/demos/chat/` successful**

[image]
my nodejs is work correctly and after start that i get this message:

```
Server listening at port 3000
```

Nodejs file content:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var addedUser = false;

    socket.on('new message', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
            username: socket.username,
            message: data
        });
    });
});
```

now i'm try to connect from android to that:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.3:3000");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
        mSocket.on("new message", onNewMessage);
        mSocket.connect();

        attemptSend();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mSocket.disconnect();
        mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
        mSocket.off("new message", onNewMessage);
    }

    private void attemptSend() {
        mSocket.emit("new message", "say hello from server");
    }

    private void leave() {
        mSocket.disconnect();
        mSocket.connect();
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.e("", "error_connect");
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            Log.e("", "onNewMessage");
        }
    };
}
```

unfortunately i get this message after run android application and that couldnot connect to nodejs:

**Logcat:**

```
error_connect
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

netstat command result:

```
mahdi sinjim-server # netstat -pan | grep 3000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27041/nodejs    
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:60146       192.168.1.3:3000        ESTABLISHED 3432/firefox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:3000        192.168.1.3:60146       ESTABLISHED 27041/nodejs
```

Comment: Debug your server with http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/. It's simple program where you can check is your server really working.

Comment: @EliaszKubala server side nodejs is correct. from android i can not connect to localhost or 192.168.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this script for connection

```
    public class TCPClient {

            private String serverMessage;
            public final String SERVERIP = Global.IPAddres; //your computer IP address
            public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
            private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
            private boolean mRun = false;

            PrintWriter out;
            BufferedReader in;

            public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
                mMessageListener = listener;
            }

            public void sendMessage(String message) {
                Log.d("log", message);
                if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
                    out.println(message);
                    out.flush();
                    if (message.equals("logout")) stopClient();
                }
            }

            public void stopClient() {
                mRun = false;
                mTcpClient = null;
            }

            public void run() {

                mRun = true;

                try {
                    //here you must put your computer's IP address.
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
                    //create a socket to make the connection with the server
                    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                    try {

                        //send the message to the server
                        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");
                        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                        //receive the message which the server sends back
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));



                        while (mRun) {
                            serverMessage = in.readLine();
                            if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                                mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                                Log.d("log", serverMessage);
                            }
                            serverMessage = null;
                        }
                        Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
                    } finally {
                        //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                        // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                        socket.close();
                        mTcpClient = null;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
                } finally {
                    mTcpClient = null;
                }
                mTcpClient = null;
            }

        }


private class startTCPClient extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(
                    new OnMessageReceived() {

                        @Override
                        //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                        public void messageReceived(String message) {
                            Log.d("log", message);

                        }
                    });
            //start client
            mTcpClient.run();
            return null;
        }
}
```

you have to execute this in onCreate method and remember to destroy that.

```
new startTCPClient().execute();
```

What's more, for example you can use this function to send test text message

```
public static void sendMessage(String s) {
        Log.d("sendMessage - ", s);        
        if (mTcpClient != null) {
            mTcpClient.sendMessage(s);
        } else {
            Log.e("Service offline", s);
        }
    }
```

I propose use this in service. 
Have fun!